# Listing rows which have the same value as an entred id in a certain column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a following table structure in Postgres:

| id | conversation_id | member_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | 73 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 |
| 8 | 3 | 73 |

How I can select all rows of members with the same **conversation_id** as the entred **member_id** (**2**) for example?

For the example above it will return rows 3, 4, 5

I tried this one query, but it does not return what I expect:

```
SELECT cu.id, cu.member_id
FROM conversation c, conversation_user cu
WHERE cu.conversation_id=c.id
GROUP BY cu.member_id, cu.id
having cu.member_id = 2
```

Comment: Please replace images by plain text in your request. What is wrong with your query ? What does it return ?

Comment: My query retruns only rows 5, I need 3, 4 and 5

Comment: does the basic query `SELECT * FROM conversation  WHERE conversation_id = 2` fit your expectation ?

Comment: I need to search by member_id not conversation_id Well I found it, i will post an edit soon

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
SELECT cu.id
FROM conversation c, conversation_user cu
WHERE cu.conversation_id=c.id 
AND cu.conversation_id = (SELECT cu2.conversation_id FROM conversation_user cu2 WHERE cu2.member_id=2 LIMIT 1)
```